# somebody can help me to align CSV document while downloading

Tags: php, mysql, flags

I have written a PHP code to download reports as a CSV file format.
But the thing i need to do is, I need to align If the DIDNo having 2 or more AgentNumber then i need to put it by side

```
ex:
DIDNo       AgentNumber 
001         12334554            12334578        1234556





<?php

                require_once('common.php');

            header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');

            // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
            $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

            // output the column headings
            fputcsv($output, array('DIDNo','AgentNumber'));

            // fetch the data
            $sql = "SELECT didNo,agentNumber FROM AGENT_INFO";

            $rows = mysql_query($sql);

            // loop over the rows, outputting them
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);


    ?>



I am getting:

    --------------------------------------------------
DIDNo          AgentNumber
3054001    994740040
3054002    994734911
3054002    908799144
3054003    999497774
3054003    960007775
3054004    442853588
3054004    999470955
3054004    960044599
3054005    999458354
3054005    814461211
```

### I need to have like this:

```
DIDNo     AgentNumber           
3054001    999440040            
3054002    999434911        908799944   
3054002             
3054003   999497774     960007775   
3054003             
3054004   442853588     999470955   960044599
3054004         
3054004             
3054005   999458354     814461211   
3054005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT didNo,
               GROUP_CONCAT(agentNumber SEPARATOR ',') as agentNumbers
          FROM AGENT_INFO
          GROUP BY didNo";
$rows = mysql_query($sql);

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) {
    $data = array();
    foreach($row as $value) {
        $data = array_merge($data, explode(',', $value));
    }
    fputcsv($output, $data);
}
```

(untested)

Comment: It works really great !!
Thanks for your time and solution, Appreciate !!

Comment: One more small doubt
I need to have one more data to it from a did_info table

Column name is "business_id"

I heard i need to use JOIN query can plz somebody help me.......

Comment: `SELECT ai.didNo, di.business_id, GROUP_CONCAT(ai.agentNumber SEPARATOR ',') as agentNumbers FROM AGENT_INFO ai LEFT JOIN did_info di ON di.didNo = ai.didNo GROUP BY ai.didNo, di.business_id`

Comment: Sorry Mark file downloading is empty :(

Comment: I had to guess at the JOIN condition, because I don't know the columns and relationships in your database.... and you should always test your SQL using command line or phpmyadmin or similar to be sure it is correct